# INNER JOIN for 3 tables

Tags: join, ms-access

I am doing a small course in SQL during my academic degree, I am very new with this material.

---

I saw [Inner joinning 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824501/inner-joining-three-tables) on StackOverflow, I tried to do INNER JOIN between my three tables, the INNER JOIN between the two tables are working well, but when I am adding the thired it's not working well, maybe I missed something?

this one is working:

```
 SELECT Actors.FirstName,Actors.LastName
 FROM Actors
 INNER JOIN ActorsMovies  ON Actors.ActorID= ActorsMovies.ActorID;
```

this one doesn't work, I get an error message that something is missing:

```
 SELECT Actors.FirstName,Actors.LastName
 FROM Actors
 INNER JOIN ActorsMovies  ON Actors.ActorID= ActorsMovies.ActorID
 INNER JOIN GenresMovies ON ActorsMovies.MovieID=GenresMovies.MovieID;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could need brackets.
Try this:

```
SELECT Actors.FirstName,Actors.LastName
FROM ((Actors
INNER JOIN ActorsMovies  ON Actors.ActorID= ActorsMovies.ActorID)
INNER JOIN GenresMovies ON ActorsMovies.MovieID=GenresMovies.MovieID);
```